# XCode: Adding password protection to an existing ios app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a huge tabbed bar application which uses storyboards and is already on the app store - but now I am adding in password protection to it.

I have already implemented a settings page in my app in which the user can toggle whether or not a password is required. They can also change their password here.

However, I can't find a solution to the next stage. Here is some code from my App Delegate:

```
-(void)requestPassword {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *passwordON = [defaults objectForKey:@"passwordBOOL"];
    if ([passwordON isEqualToString:@"ON"]) {
        NSLog(@"ON");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Off");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am detecting whether or not the password is on or off. If the password is on, how do I go to a different view or set up an overlay password entry view? I am not sure if I should have a separate view for this or run some code from the first view of my app.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: i would let the viewcontrollers test if the password is required and if it is unlocked. if yes/yes, everything is ok. if yes/no i would overlay the whole view with a dark view (black 80% alpha or so) and add an UIAlertView Name/Password form.

Comment: I was thinking that. But what function do I put the code in in the viewController? I only want to test the password once when the app is launched or is restored after viewing a different app (i.e. closing the app, even for a second, will require re-entry of the password).

Comment: a (probably not very clean) method would be to check in applicationdidenterforeground, and if necessary send a NSNotification  to all viewcontroller and the currently active will handle the display hiding/entry.

Comment: Doesn't take care of the alpha overlay, but your appdelegate create and be the delegate to UIAlertView - no need to send around and listen for notifications.

Comment: @MichaelKernahan Yes, putting a simple alert box requesting the password works (and is so easy to implement), but does not look as professional as the overlay with input entry. I guess it will work for now until I can work out how to call a modal view controller from the app delegate.

Comment: Your pages could register themselves with the delegate when they are displayed. This would give the delegate a reference to the current VC at all times. Then code for modal can be in the delegate put send the message to the correct vc.

Comment: Sounds interesting. How would I go about doing that?